# UnitSimplify for unit multiples and submultiples

Tags: output-formatting, formatting, units

Is there any way to automatically rewrite units so that they display more naturally looking magnitudes? By this I mean that

```
{Quantity[1000,"m"],Quantity[3600,"s"]}
```

Could equivalently be shown as

```
{Quantity[1,"km"],Quantity[1,"h"]}
```

I would like to do this for user-facing functions, where it's much more meaningful to see `Quantity[1,"day"]` instead of `Quantity[86400,"s"]`

**Note:**

- I am looking for a function automatically choosing whether to do this, and how to do it, as opposed to manually using `UnitConvert` (think of how your OS displays file sizes in reasonable-looking units instead of always using bytes).
- `UnitSimplify` doesn't seem to be able to do this, as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 4):

This is a difficult problem: What is the "best" unit to choose?

To get started, let's make a list of all available units (thanks [Fidel I. Schaposnik](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/45839/fidel-i-schaposnik)):

```
allunits = QuantityUnits`$UnitList;
```

and then define a function that gives me all units that are compatible with a given unit:

```
allcompatibleunits[x_] := Select[allunits, CompatibleUnitQ[#, x] &]
```

For example, there are lots of units that are compatible with `Second`:

```
allcompatibleunits["Second"]
(*    {"AcademicBimesters", "AcademicQuarters", "AcademicQuinmesters",
      ...
       "Yottaseconds", "Zeptoseconds", "Zettaseconds"}    *)
```

(there are 216 of them, some very exotic).

Let's convert something to all compatible units:

```
allconversions[x_] := UnitConvert[x, #] & /@ allcompatibleunits[x]
```

For your case of 1000 meters,

```
allconversions[Quantity[1000, "m"]]
(*    {Quantity[720000000/1397, "AgateLines"],
       Quantity[15625/25146, "AirMiles"],
       Quantity[324.25, "Akainas"],
       ...
       Quantity[Interval[{3472.2222222222194`, 4166.66666666667}], "Zarot"],
       Quantity[1000000000000000000000000, "Zeptometers"], 
       Quantity[1/1000000000000000000, "Zettameters"]}    *)
```

Now we need to pick the "best" one of these. What exactly are your criteria? We could for example pick the number that is closest to unity:

```
bestconversion[x_] := 
  MinimalBy[allconversions[x], Abs[Log[QuantityMagnitude[#]]] &]

bestconversion[Quantity[1000, "m"]]
(*    {Quantity[1, "Kilometers"],
       Quantity[1, "LengthClicks"]}    *)

bestconversion[Quantity[3600, "s"]]
(*    {Quantity[1, "Hours"]}    *)

bestconversion[Quantity[86400, "s"]]
(*    {Quantity[1, "CivialDays"],
       Quantity[1, "Days"],
       Quantity[1, "MayanKins"],
       Quantity[1, "MesopotamianDays"],
       Quantity[1, "Nychthemerons"]}    *)

bestconversion[Quantity[86100, "s"]]
(*    {Quantity[0.9992561804, "SiderealDays"]}    *)
```

You'll probably have to hand-pick the `allunits` list to get what you want, to avoid esoteric units. For example, we can pick out metric units in order to narrow things down a bit:

```
metricunits = Quiet[Union[
  Cases[QuantityUnit[UnitConvert[#, "Metric"]] & /@ allunits, _String]]];
allcompatibleunits[x_] := Select[metricunits, CompatibleUnitQ[#, x] &]

bestconversion[Quantity[1000, "m"]]
(*    {Quantity[1, "Kilometers"]}    *)

bestconversion[Quantity[3600, "s"]]
(*    {Quantity[1, "Hours"]}    *)

bestconversion[Quantity[86400, "s"]]
(*    {Quantity[1, "Days"]}    *)

bestconversion[Quantity[86100, "s"]]
(*    {Quantity[287/288, "Days"]}    *)
```

which is a bit more sensible.

All this works only with base units, not derived units.

Comment: I agree that this is a hard problem not because of its computational aspects, but because of the difficulty in choosing the "best" unit. What do you think of "choosing the unit with the shortest name" among those that generate a number closest to unity? That might end up finding the most commonly used units, at least in the examples you provided. (+1)

Comment: I still think the problem shouldn't be as hard as this, since in fact most units belong to some scale and we'd probably like to stay on it: it makes sense to convert 1000 m to 1 km, or 0.3 Russian Skewed Sazhens to 1 Russian Shags, but why try to mix the two?

Comment: On a couple of somewhat related comments, `QuantityUnits\`$UnitList` seems simpler to get the list of all available units (at least in v12.2), and `CommonUnits` seems to implement some sort of heuristic to find suitable unit matches... I would have tried to exploit it for this problem, except `CommonUnits@{Quantity[1000, "m"], Quantity[1, "km"]}` gives `{Quantity[1000, "Meters"], Quantity[1000, "Meters"]}` instead of the more reasonable `{Quantity[1, "Kilometers"], Quantity[1, "Kilometers"]}`. Maybe mathemattica does have some concept of unit scales, deeper inside?

Comment: @FidelI.Schaposnik For keeping Russian Shags to Russian Skewed Sazhens, I think we'll have to subdivide the unit list manually into desirable joint-blocks. I don't see a way to automate this subdivision. This is exactly what I meant when I said this was a hard problem.

Comment: @MarcoB I don't know how to pick by useful shortest name, because [`QuantityUnit`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/QuantityUnit.html) returns strings like `Meters` and `Seconds` instead of `m` and `s`, so the simple units aren't all that short in name. In fact, minimizing the unit's name (string length) will convert all time units to [cés](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_time#History) which are centi-days, and all distances to [ems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Em_(typography)) and [ens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/En_(typography)) and others.